# C# - Access variables in a mixed way?

Tags: c#, linq, variables

Hey guys I was wondering how to access some variables like a text, i mean like the ex. below

```
string variable1;
string variable2;
methodName(int variablenum){
   //Let's say the int is 1
   //How can I access variable1?
   //Sth like variable+"variablenum"
}
```

**Edit** : Well, what if the variables would be **variableA**, **variableB**, how would I access them?

Comment: Have you tried using reflection?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use an array instead?

Comment: I would strongly consider using a different data structure. You might be able to use reflection to get your string, but the overhead isn't worth it, IMO.

Comment: Your question is not all that clear. Bear in mind that C# is strongly typed, strings are strings and ints are ints. If you want to interpret a string as an int, you have to parse the string eg. int.Parse(myString); if you want to use an int as a string, it's a little easier because intrinsic types like ints have a ToString method.

Comment: I'd say to use an array, so instead of `variable1` and `variable2` you have `variables[0]` and `variables[1]` (remembering the zero-based index). Then you just do `variables[variablenum]`, or `variablenum - 1` if it has to be 1-based. You can't stick a number onto a string and then access it as a variable name (at least, not without a load of nasty reflection).

Comment: Hmm, how could i make an array of variables? I mean arrayname.variableA, arrayname.variableB

Answer (score 5):

Using reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.MethodName(1);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private string variable1 = "1";
    private string variable2 = "2";

    public void MethodName(int variablenum)
    {
        // .Instance because not static, .NonPublic because private
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        FieldInfo field = GetType().GetField("variable" + variablenum, flags);
        string s = (string)field.GetValue(this);          
    }
}
```

Comment: TO OP: It is strongly recommended to reconsider your code strategy, because it is bad.

Comment: To be fair, it's a good solution to a questionable problem. :)

Comment: Could you //comment in the BindingFlags things to understand what you doing? :D I'm beginner and i just need C# to program a bit my serverside of the game

Comment: Sure. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx as well

Comment: What's the references to these? because i imported system.reflection and it says `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'

Comment: Your `MethodName` method is probably static?!

Comment: It is static because if i delete static it will say `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`

Comment: Probably because your field is static. Remove static in both declarations and it should be ok

Comment: If you're a beginner to OOP, you shouldn't be playing with reflection. You should start with learning about Class objects and organizing your variables in meaningful ways. A better solution will come to you.

Comment: @Bidou: I did and it says `Program' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point` @MadHenchbot: I'm just beginner in C#

Comment: The `Main` method must be static. The `MethodName` method should not. Both fields (`variable1` and `variable2`) should not. In the `Main` method, use `test` and not `Test` to call the `MethodName` method

Comment: The output is 1, not variable 1 lol... btw maybe it's easier to make an array, and put there variables? (like arrayname.variableA)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an array gives you what you want, but beware the out of range errors possible:

```
string [] variables = { "foo", "bar", "baz" }
string methodName( int variableIndex )
{
    return variables[ variableIndex ]; // bad if variable > 2
}
```

Comment: Hmm i don't think this would do if i would want to access VariableA or VariableB (check the edited post)

Comment: It's the same. The variableIndex is just accessing a variable at a particular place in the array. The *name* of the variable(s) makes no difference. string [] stuff = { varX, varY, varZ };